# How do I disable MongoDB establishing a connection on start in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot application that has two different database implementations, one is SQL, one is NO-SQL (MongoDB). The SQL implementation is default and I am not using currently the NO-SQL one. However, the application tries to connect to a MongoDB server and shows an error if one is not available.

I tried the following:

```java
    SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
    })
```

However, in this case I get the following error:

```
    Field operations in ...mongodb.CustomThingRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' that could not be found.
```

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
```

```
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    
    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' in your configuration.
```

My MongoDB Repository classes look as follows:

```java
    public interface SpringDataMongoThingRepository extends MongoRepository<ThingDocument, String>,
            CustomThingRepository<ThingDocument, String> {
    }

    public interface CustomThingRepository<T, ID> {
    
        [...]
    
        <S extends T> S save(S entity);
    
        void deleteById(ID id);
    }

    @Component
    public class CustomThingRepositoryImpl<T, ID> implements CustomThingRepository<T, ID> {
    
        @Autowired
        private MongoOperations operations;
        
        @Autowired
        private ThingDataStorageProcessor thingDataStorageProcessor;
        [...]


    @Component
    public class ThingDataStorageProcessor {
    
        @Autowired
        private GridFsOperations gridFsOperations;
        [...]
```

I tried providing dummy implementations of MongoOperations and GridFsOperations but I still get an error:

```
    Description:
    
    A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.
    
    
    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

How can I at least prevent MongoDB  from connecting on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
@Repository
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb", name = "uri")
public interface SpringDataMongoThingRepository...
```